# Can this promise nesting be changed to chaining?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, chaining, angular-promise

This is the pseudo scenario

```
           | then (items)          | then (items, actions)
getItems() | getActions(for:items) | apply(actions -> items)
 :promise  |  :promise             | model <= items
           |                       |  :synchronous
```

So in words:

1. I need to get a list of global items.
2. Fine. Items fetched.
3. Make a request for actions that user has taken over previously fetched items.
4. Fine. Actions fetched.
5. Apply actions to items list.
6. Put items on the model and display in view.

This is somewhat the code I'm using

```
return itemsResource
       .getItems(userId)
       .$promise
       .then(function(items) {
           return actionsResource
                  .getActions(items.map(i => i.id)) // pseudo mapper code here
                  .$promise
                  .then(function(actions) { // THIS IS NESTED so it sees both promise results
                      return [items, actions];
                  });
       })
       .then(helper.spread(function(items, actions) {
           applyActions(items, actions);
           $scope.model.items = items;
           return items;
       }));
```

As you can understand I can't use `$q.all` initially because second (actions) promise depends on results of the first one (items).

**Why not return actions with items?** Because I'm caching items for all users, so item fetching is really quick. This is similar to how Stackoverflow works. They just return questions regardless of user requesting them. Then they subsequently also request for preferred and ignored tags and apply to fetched questions. This scales very well, otherwise SO would require many more servers to handle just initial list of questions for all users, because every user's request would yield different results, so caching wouldn't make much sense.

**Why not apply items to `$scope` immediately after being fetched?** This would eliminate the additional nested `then`, that's true. but I'm not doing that because there are few more steps afterwards and every time one of the promises gets resolved at least one `$digest` cycle is being executed. With many items (being rather complex objects) this can account for quite some processing. That's the reason I'm holding on to passing items to the view to the very last moment possible.

### Question

Is there a way to avoid the nested `then` beside these two workarounds:

1. Apply items to `$scope` as soon as possible
2. Save items to local variable and use it afterwards

I'd like to flatten my code as much as possible without introduction of additional resources if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this should be fairly straightforward, no?

(I have simplified some of your internal function signatures for clarity)

```
itemsResource.getItems(userId)
  .then(function(items) {
    return $q.all({
      items: items,
      actions: actionResource.getActions(items)
    });
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    applyActions(data.items, data.actions);
    $scope.model.items = data.items;
    return data.items;
  });
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gN3168zEWKJRv2UTnGrz?p=preview) for illustration

Comment: Will $q.all ignore hash values that aren't promises? I've never tried it with an object.

Comment: It will just return the (non-promise) object. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gN3168zEWKJRv2UTnGrz?p=preview)

Comment: Nifty. nice approach.

Comment: @BertEvans, thanks. I think SO has a system of expressing approval of answers ;)

Comment: Even if we supplied array instead of an object it would likely work. First array element would be immediately resolved while we'd have to wait for the second. I'll surely have to investigate this object passing to `$q.all`. Have to check angular source and kowalski's docs...

Comment: You're right. Angular documentation says "an array or hash of promises". I think I'm never going to provide arrays any more. Because indices are so inconvenient compared to named members when reading results. Thanks for this. I'll accept this as correct answer because it eliminates nesting in the best possible way while also simplifying the whole block of code.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, yes, I prefer the hash-variant, which is why I used it here.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the results of the items->actions chain in a promise? Something like

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

    var outerItems;

    itemsResource.getItems(userId).$promise
        .then(getActions)
        .then(function (actions) {
            resolve([outerItems, actions]);
        })
        .catch(function (err) { reject(err); });

    function getActions(items) {
        outerItems = items;
        return actionsResource.getActions(items).$promise
    }

}).then(function (itemAndActions) {
    var items = itemsAndActions[0], 
        actions = itemsAndActions[1];

    return helper.spread(function (items, actions) {
        applyActions(items, actions);
        $scope.model.items = items;
        return items;
    })
});
```

Comment: Your code is even more convoluted than the original one, don't you think? Execution of code lines is now not sequential which makes it much harder to read and maintain. And you've used local variable, and nesting both of which I was trying to avoid if at all possible. And local variable I was able to eliminate from my code for the cost of promise nesting.