# Using Angular's $q.all with codependent promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, es6-promise

Second promise needs result of the first promise as a parameter.
I [have seen an example](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/) of solving this problem with ES6 promises.

```
firstThingAsync()  
  .then(function(result1) {
    return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(result1), secondThingAsync(result1)]); 
  })
  .then(function(result1, result2) {
    // do something with result1 and result2
  })
  .catch(function(err){ /* ... */ });
```

But I am not sure what $q function has similar behavior to Promise.resolve. Any ideas?

Comment: I answered a similar question before: [Can this promise nesting be changed to chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637388/can-this-promise-nesting-be-changed-to-chaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular 1.4 you can use `$q.resolve(result1)`.

Source: [Angular 1.4 $q.resolve docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve).

In older versions you can use `$q.defer().resolve(result1)`.

Source: [Angular 1.3 Deferred API docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api).